# use IP tables to redirect some (ip based) traffic

Tags: iptables, iptables-redirect

I have a laptop that forwards all the traffic from one interface to another.

I followed the instruction provided for different question, and it works.

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

and add the following rules to iptables
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --out-interface eth1 -j MASQUERADE  
sudo iptables -A FORWARD --in-interface eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Now, I would like to set a rule for traffic matching a certain destination IP and port to be redirected to a local server.
I tried something like:

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT --src 0/0 --dst 55.55.55.55 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:4433
```

Actually I tried a few others, but without success. At best, I get redirected only the traffic that is generated locally (and not the transit traffic).

What should I try next?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect traffic to local server then use PREROUTING instead of OUTPUT chain like

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -d 55.55.55.55/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1

Comment: Using the REDIRECT target is probably better, that is explicitly for redirecting traffic to the local host.